# Network connection issue. Connection breaks sometimes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have internet delivered by wifi to my house. Every day about 20:00  i have problem with browsing. I got information form firefox like "Unable to connect" then i need to refresh couple times to load site. Problem occurs on all devices(2 laptops, android phones...).

I replaced my router to TL-WR1043, replaced ethernet cabel and provider replaced his router. No changes.

Network topology:

(provider wifi network) --> provider router---> etherent -->my router --> wifi --> laptop, phone, etc.

Example traces:

```
traceroute to google.pl (173.194.35.88), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router (192.168.0.1)  0.894 ms  1.743 ms  1.744 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  4.046 ms  4.063 ms  4.058 ms
 3  10.1.6.254 (10.1.6.254)  18.326 ms  18.341 ms  19.214 ms
 4  89.174.230.41 (89.174.230.41)  20.596 ms  44.371 ms  44.355 ms
 5  157.25.248.65 (157.25.248.65)  34.991 ms  35.000 ms  44.294 ms
 6  193.85.195.37 (193.85.195.37)  41.653 ms  41.410 ms  42.623 ms
 7  193.85.195.94 (193.85.195.94)  39.972 ms  31.857 ms  31.823 ms
 8  74.125.49.1 (74.125.49.1)  31.806 ms  31.771 ms  31.747 ms
 9  72.14.238.44 (72.14.238.44)  47.942 ms 72.14.238.46 (72.14.238.46)  33.389 ms 72.14.238.44 (72.14.238.44)  33.349 ms
10  72.14.234.235 (72.14.234.235)  33.367 ms 72.14.234.237 (72.14.234.237)  39.552 ms 72.14.234.233 (72.14.234.233)  39.562 ms
11  209.85.241.213 (209.85.241.213)  54.631 ms 216.239.48.116 (216.239.48.116)  64.162 ms 209.85.241.213 (209.85.241.213)  70.735 ms
12  66.249.94.138 (66.249.94.138)  55.451 ms 66.249.95.61 (66.249.95.61)  54.572 ms 216.239.48.121 (216.239.48.121)  49.943 ms
13  bud02s21-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.35.88)  49.916 ms 66.249.95.61 (66.249.95.61)  49.885 ms bud02s21-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.35.88)  40.567 ms


traceroute to google.pl (173.194.35.95), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router (192.168.0.1)  1.679 ms  1.943 ms  1.945 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  2.632 ms  3.220 ms  3.572 ms
 3  10.1.6.254 (10.1.6.254)  16.109 ms  16.104 ms  18.818 ms
 4  89.174.230.41 (89.174.230.41)  19.643 ms  19.655 ms  20.989 ms
 5  157.25.248.65 (157.25.248.65)  35.436 ms  34.454 ms  35.422 ms
 6  193.85.195.37 (193.85.195.37)  44.985 ms  43.268 ms  43.137 ms
 7  193.85.195.94 (193.85.195.94)  41.740 ms  31.809 ms  30.958 ms
 8  74.125.49.1 (74.125.49.1)  31.904 ms 10.1.6.254 (10.1.6.254)  15.459 ms !H  15.468 ms !H


traceroute to google.pl (173.194.35.87), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router (192.168.0.1)  1.580 ms  1.873 ms  1.871 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  2.395 ms  3.015 ms  3.616 ms
 3  10.1.6.254 (10.1.6.254)  19.616 ms  19.626 ms  19.619 ms
 4  89.174.230.41 (89.174.230.41)  22.917 ms  22.928 ms  24.106 ms
 5  157.25.248.65 (157.25.248.65)  38.471 ms  38.476 ms  39.390 ms
 6  193.85.195.37 (193.85.195.37)  47.090 ms  45.562 ms  46.200 ms
 7  193.85.195.94 (193.85.195.94)  39.255 ms  30.743 ms  30.611 ms
 8  74.125.49.1 (74.125.49.1)  31.210 ms  31.213 ms  31.203 ms
 9  72.14.238.44 (72.14.238.44)  33.061 ms 72.14.238.46 (72.14.238.46)  33.076 ms  37.338 ms
10  72.14.234.235 (72.14.234.235)  37.348 ms 72.14.234.233 (72.14.234.233)  38.696 ms  38.705 ms
11  209.85.241.213 (209.85.241.213)  54.160 ms  54.160 ms  54.152 ms
12  66.249.95.61 (66.249.95.61)  55.387 ms  54.130 ms  55.328 ms
13  bud02s21-in-f23.1e100.net (173.194.35.87)  46.961 ms 10.1.6.254 (10.1.6.254)  16.612 ms !H  16.582 ms !H


traceroute to google.pl (173.194.35.88), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router (192.168.0.1)  1.575 ms  2.042 ms  2.043 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  2.704 ms  3.473 ms  3.477 ms
 3  10.1.6.254 (10.1.6.254)  17.370 ms  18.147 ms  24.811 ms
 4  10.1.6.254 (10.1.6.254)  26.737 ms !H  26.745 ms !H  26.731 ms !H


traceroute to google.pl (173.194.35.95), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router (192.168.0.1)  1.378 ms  1.479 ms  1.475 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  2.740 ms  3.175 ms  3.574 ms
 3  10.1.6.254 (10.1.6.254)  19.076 ms  19.087 ms  19.894 ms
 4  89.174.230.41 (89.174.230.41)  23.181 ms  23.175 ms  23.830 ms
 5  157.25.248.65 (157.25.248.65)  32.888 ms  43.080 ms  43.073 ms
 6  193.85.195.37 (193.85.195.37)  43.065 ms  42.830 ms  42.776 ms
 7  193.85.195.94 (193.85.195.94)  41.564 ms  30.808 ms  32.009 ms
 8  74.125.49.1 (74.125.49.1)  41.213 ms  41.226 ms  41.928 ms
 9  72.14.238.44 (72.14.238.44)  41.994 ms 72.14.238.46 (72.14.238.46)  32.223 ms *
10  72.14.234.237 (72.14.234.237)  33.109 ms 209.85.251.248 (209.85.251.248)  34.425 ms  34.428 ms
11  209.85.241.213 (209.85.241.213)  55.862 ms 216.239.48.116 (216.239.48.116)  96.446 ms 72.14.234.10 (72.14.234.10)  56.839 ms
12  66.249.95.61 (66.249.95.61)  55.837 ms 66.249.94.138 (66.249.94.138)  57.865 ms 66.249.95.61 (66.249.95.61)  56.704 ms
13  66.249.95.61 (66.249.95.61)  48.494 ms  48.255 ms bud02s21-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.35.95)  48.799 ms
```

In traces you can see H!. That means host unrechable. I sent it to my provider but he said that this means nothing because some hosts can reject traceroute. Pings are ok.

Can you help me to find/diagnose where the issue is?

This may by helpful:

[image]

Comment: Based on the trace, my guess would be its a issue in GTS Poland's network. It looks like you hit their internal network (the 10.1.*.* addresses), but you never make it back out (the addresses in the range 89.174.230.40 - 89.174.230.43).

Comment: 10.1.*.* is my provider internal network address. You mean address at position 3?

Answer (score 0):

Some ISP disconnect every 24 hours to give you a new dynamic IP address. Check with your ISP if this is true for your contract and if they can schedule the disconnection to time like 2:30am when you are not using your internet access.

Comment: Reconnection should take no more than couple seconds/minutes. But connection problems occur by about 2 hours. I think this is too long for reconnection.

Comment: You are right. I misinterpreted your "I need to refresh couple times to load site" so that the error is corrected after one minute. It is OK that some hosts refuses to anwser upon traceroute as long as you can ping the distination.

Comment: So how to diagnose where the problem is? Do you know some tools to monitor network and find issues?